# Handle Exception in SecurityWebFilterChain bean

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

### Description

I used zalando problem spring webflux to simplfy the exception handling.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport::class)
class SecurityConfig{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var problemSupport: SecurityProblemSupport

    //...
    @Bean
    fun springWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain = http {
        //....
        exceptionHandling {
            authenticationEntryPoint = problemSupport
            accessDeniedHandler = problemSupport
        }
        authorizeExchange {
            //...
            authorize(pathMatchers("/{id}/**"), customCheck())
            //...
        }
   }
   
   fun customCheck():ReactiveAuthenctionManager<AuthenticationContext>{
      // a runtime IllegalArgumentException was thrown here.
   }
}
```

I have created an exception handler for `IllegalArgumentException`, it is working well for handling the exceptions from controllers.

### Expected Behavior

Handling `IllegalArgumentException` via exception handler(configured the accessDeniedHandler to zalando global problemHandle), return a 400 status.

### Actual Behavior

But it throws a 500 internal error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved myself.

If you think this can be categorized as an authorization error, use a `try/catch` and return a failure Authorization Decision in the `catch` block.

```kotlin
fun customCheck():ReactiveAuthenctionManager<AuthenticationContext>=
  ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext> { authenticationMono, context -> 
    try{
       //...
    }catch(e: Exception){
       AuthorizationDesiion(false)
    }
}
```

The second possible approach, if you want to process exceptions such as UUID conversion failure as general errors, create a custom `WebExceptionHandler` bean is enough.

```kotlin
@Component
@Order(-2)
class MyWebExceptionHandler:WebExceptionHandler() {}
```

Note setup a `Order(-2)` on the bean class to ensure it has the highest priority in execution time. An example of custom `WebExceptionHandler` is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-exception-handler/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L117).